# How to reload webpage AFTER executing an ajax post request?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm currently implementing multi-language support for my personal website (which I'm also rebuilding completely atm), I need to reload the page AFTER an AJAX post request. I'm saving the preferred language in a session & when changing it, it'll of course be updated & I need to reload the page in order to display the correct translation. The problem is that with method, the page sometimes will be reloaded BEFORE changing the preferred language in the session which then of course results in the AJAX post request not to be executed.

Javascript:

```
function setLang(lang) {
    $.post("languages/setLang.php", {"preflang":lang});
    location.reload();
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['PREFERRED_LANGUAGE'] = $_POST['preflang'];
?>
```

Comment: wait for the ASYNC operation to complete... aka: do the redirect from the success-handler

Comment: Well that solution is too obvious for my brain... It of course works now, thanks!

Comment: I'd guess the modern way would be a Promise... alas, I'm not very good with frontend stuff ;)

Answer (score 2):

how about sending ajax using $.ajax

JS:

```
function setLang(lang) {
$.ajax({
          url:"languages/setLang.php",
          type:'POST',
          data:{"preflang":lang},
          dataType:'text',

          success:function(response){
            if(response=='true'){
              location.reload();
            }
          }
        });
}
```

PHP

```php
    <?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['PREFERRED_LANGUAGE'] = $_POST['preflang'];
    echo 'true';
    ?>
```

this way the success function will run only when ajax call returns a response after executing code from server and than you can reload page.